# How to refer to Class Objects in PHP

Tags: php, class, object

I need to refer to each of components like to,message-price... etc

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [message-count] => 1 

    [messages] => Array ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object ( 
            [to] => 256754106703 
            [message-price] => 0.00700000 
            [status] => 0 
            [message-id] => 020000001AF86AE5 
            [remaining-balance] => 1.80010000 
            [network] => 64101 
        )
     )
)
```

How do I do it ?

Comment: `$myClassObject->messages[0]->id`; `$myClassObject->messages[0]->{'message-price'}`; `$myClassObject->messages[0]->network`; etc

Comment: @MarkBaker  Nice job just what I needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do:

```
echo $yourObj->messages[0]->{'message-price'};
```